# Prove $P(X\ge \lambda EX)\ge (1-\lambda)^2\frac{(EX)^2}{EX^2}$ if $X$ positive r.v., finite variance

Tags: probability-theory

Prove $\displaystyle P(X\ge \lambda EX)\ge (1-\lambda)^2\frac{(EX)^2}{EX^2}$ if $X$ positive r.v., finite variance and $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

I wanted to use Chebyshev's inequality but the sign in the problem is the opposite to what it is in Chebyshev. How can I approach this, perhaps using indicator functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we prove the following inequality:

For any $a>0$, 
$$
EX\leq a+E(1_{X\geq a} X)$$

The proof of this is by splitting $EX$:
$$
EX=E(1_{X<a} X)+ E(1_{X\geq a} X)\leq a+E(1_{X\geq a} X).$$

We use the above when $a=\lambda EX$, then we have
$$
E(1-\lambda)X \leq E(1_{X\geq \lambda EX} X)$$

Now square both sides and use Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$(1-\lambda)^2(EX)^2=(E(1-\lambda)X)^2\leq (E(1_{X\geq \lambda EX} X))^2\leq E(1_{X\geq \lambda EX}^2)EX^2.$$

Hence, we have the result:
$$(1-\lambda)^2 (EX)^2\leq P(X\geq \lambda EX) EX^2.$$